# In React why is the render method bound to component instance but not custom methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, scope, event-handling

In a class, why is the render method automatically bound to the component instance but custom methods e.g. event handlers aren't?

I understand using the bind keyword to make these event handlers work but was just trying to find an answer why "this" can be referenced in the render method but why it's also not automatically bound in event handler methods?

Comment: It's not just `render`, it's *every* lifecycle function that's already bound. And that's the case because they already have been inside React library itself. So you don't have to. You obviously have to for custom ones because React doesn't know what your custom methods will be called

Comment: Ah ok so you're saying the lifecycle methods are bound also but we just don't get to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is the render method automatically bound to the component instance

It isn't bound. It's just that react always calls the render function using the correct context.

For normal functions, the value of `this` is determined by how you call the function. In the following code, `example.` is the part that says what the value of `this` will be inside the function.

```js
const example = {
  value: 'abc',
  printValue: function () {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

example.printValue(); // abc
```

But if you call the function in a different way, you can get a different value of `this`.

```js
const example = {
  value: 'abc',
  printValue: function () {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

const temp = example.printValue;

console.log(temp === example.printValue); // true (they're literally the same function)
temp(); // undefined, or throw an exception depending on if we're in strict mode
```

So every time react calls the render function, it calls it the first way (or something equivalent to it), not the second way.

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is when render is called, React is providing the correct context behind the scenes...same for any other lifecycle method?

When we add cusom methods e.g. event handlers, we have to specify it?

Answer (score 0):

Citing [React's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. **In
> JavaScript, class methods are not [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) by default.** If you forget to
> bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined
> when the function is actually called.

Defining them as arrow functions though, still at instance level, will change the scope to the component's instance. So all other methods like `render`, `componentDidMount` are part of the class' definition and are not event handler, which means `this` will point to the instance in them (the usual JavaScript behaviour for such methods).

And lastly, you can always call a method with a different scope with [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), changing what `this` refers to in those methods.